# AttributeError: EchoFactory instance has no attribute 'doStart'

Tags: python, twisted

I'm learning Twisted and here is my very first server example:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Protocol):
    def buildProtocal(self, addr):
       return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

And I got this error, I tried to reinstall the library but it still didn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/trieu/Desktop/server.py", line 11, in <module>
reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", 
line 495, in listenTCP
p.startListening()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 998, 
in startListening
self.factory.doStart()
AttributeError: EchoFactory instance has no attribute 'doStart'
```

Answer (score 4):

`EchoFactory` should extend `protocol.Factory`, not `protocol.Protocol`. Also, you have a typo in the overridden method name, `buildProtocol`.